# imacros select text and delete it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

Can iMacros select text int text box and delete so that it can later fill the text with another?

I tried with CONTENT=  command but it didn't work.

Comment: content=<sp> should do the trick, but if content command does not work, probably it is because it is not regular text box, but some kind of javascript element

Comment: You are are right. This did the job. Thanks.